# C++ preprocessing error in the code

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

```
    #include "iostream"
    #include "string"

    using namespace std;

    #define AA(bb) \
            string(::##bb);
    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {

            AA(aa);
    }
```

This gives me a bunch of errors but I am trying to understand this error:

> pre.cpp:11:1: error: pasting "::" and "aa" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::` is already a separate token, you don't need the `##` token-pasting operator for the code you showed.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the ## characters as they are not allowed in this context.  ## is to concatenate bits to make a token, but :: should be one token and whatever bb is should be another, separate, token.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes little sense as there is no symbol `aa` in scope.  Perhaps you trying to stringify the argument to your macro?  If so, what you want is:

```
#define AA(bb) string(#bb)
```

This would then convert `AA(aa)` to `string("aa")`